# Problems of designer file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Whenever I open an existing project in VS 2005, the `designer.cs` files do not show up under `.aspx` files, and due to this when I add controls in `.aspx` the `designer.cs` is not updated.

Below is how the structure looks:

```
+----AAAConfirm.aspx
.  .
.  ..AAAConfirm.aspx.cs
.
.----AAAConfirm.aspx.designer.cs
```

Comment: have you tried show all files?

Comment: I've edited the csproj file by hand to fix this.  I don't have a 2005 project to give details directions though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "show all files" for the project, it most likely got removed from the project file by accident. When you see the file in Visual Studio, right click the file and select "Add to Project".

**Or**

Check the project file and make sure the designer file's compile tag has a child element called `DependentUpon`

The XML section specifying the file's inclusion in the project should look something like this

```
<Compile Include="AAAConfirm.aspx.designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>AAAConfirm.aspx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Also check that the markup page `AAAConfirm.aspx` has the correct codebehind and inherit reference in the `<%Page>` tag. Did you maybe change namespaces? Try setting the `Inherits` attribute value to the class name without the namespace.

Comment: Well the file is visible as i have mentioned in above example.Issue is the hierarchy. Usually aspx.cs(codebehind) and designer.cs come under same(.aspx) level. But comes different for me as shown above.

Comment: @Danny, I updated my answer. Give my other suggestion a try too.

Comment: As per your first solution files are already included in the project, as when i right click shows option -> exclude from project.

As per second solution :
XML section specifying the file's inclusion in the project should looks like

'<Compile Include="Forms\AAAConfirm.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>AAAConfirm.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Forms\AAAConfirm.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>AAAConfirm.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>'

Comment: Did change namespaces. Tried setting the Inherits attribute value to the class name without the namespace.Still same issue.Designer.cs is not updated and so I am not able to access controls in codebehind.

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if you copied the `Page` tag for AAAConfirm.aspx. I might be able to help further if you still need the assistance.

Comment: Got it working. Had issues while unziping folder.Anyways Thanks for the help.

Comment: So maybe they didn't unzip to the proper folder? I imagine you decided to move your pages to a different folder and updated the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your project to some other folder and

- Locate the corrupted aspx.designer.cs file through the Solution
- Explorer Delete only the designer.cs file from your project
- Rightclick your main aspx file and select “Convert to Web
  Application“.

Ref : [Tip: regenerate aspx.designer.cs files when corrupted](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/07/tip-regenerate-aspx-designer-cs-files-when-corrupted/)